# Fully custom view with animations for UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I want to make a drop-in replacement for `UINavigationBar` with custom controls and transition animations. When I say "custom", I don't mean just tweaking around the edges like changing colours/title or placing custom views inside left/right `UIBarButton` slots, I mean a completely custom view and animations.

However, customisation capabilities of `UINavigationBar` are limited, as it has its own opaque internal hierarchy of views, which is ill-advised to tamper with.

The question is, is there any way to have a replacement for the navigation bar without having to also rewrite `UINavigationController`?

I'm also open to alternatives where the stock navigation bar is completely hidden and a custom navigation bar animates alongside pop/push transition animations.

Comment: In my opinion the best option would be to simple hide the UINavigationBar and replace your own custom view in it's place. You would have total control over it. Custom animations can be applied to it as you like

Comment: @ShayanJalil yeah but the missing bit here is how to align your custom bar animation with the UIViewController transition animation

Comment: If you want a push animation, you can achieve that by simply putting a UIView in the place where the navigation bar is. Put all your  customization code in viewDidLoad. When this ViewController will be pushed, your custom bar should animate along with the viewController

Comment: @ShayanJalil That's... super-gross. I absolutely do not want the bar embedded inside the target view controllers. Plus, I want the navigation bar to have a different animation than the view controllers themselves.